# Transfer mongo commands to Java but it doesn't work

Tags: mongodb

mongo commands:

```js
db.tissue_source.aggregate([{
$match:{

        "tissue_backups.23c5bd57da4e461caae0bbf2b06997b8": {
            $all: [{
                    $elemMatch: {
                        "63173253349670": {
                            $regex: ".*?正常.*"
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        "63173253349670": {
                            $regex: ".*?出库.*"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
               
}
}])
```

commands can run successfully in mongo client:

[image]

transfer into Java:

```
BasicDBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match",
                new BasicDBObject("tissue_backups.23c5bd57da4e461caae0bbf2b06997b8",
                        new BasicDBObject("$all", Arrays.asList(
                                new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch",
                                        new BasicDBObject("63173253349670", "正常")),
                                new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch",
                                        new BasicDBObject("63173253349670", "出库"))
                        ))
                )
        );
```

when I use aggregate to query

```
......
......
dbObjectList.add(match);
Cursor aggregateOutput = MongoKit.getCollection(collectionName).aggregate(dbObjectList, AggregationOptions.builder()
                .allowDiskUse(true)
                .build());
```

it throws the exception as follows:

> com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 2: '$or/$and/$nor entries need to be full objects' on server 127.0.0.1:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "$or/$and/$nor entries need to be full objects", "code" : 2, "codeName" : "BadValue" }

and I print the BasicDBObject content,it's the same with command:

```
System.out.println(match.toJson());
```

```js
{ "$match" : { "$or" : [{ "$or" : [{ "tissue_backups.23c5bd57da4e461caae0bbf2b06997b8" : { "$all" : [{ "$elemMatch" : { "63173253349670" : { "$regex" : ".*?正常.*" } } }, { "$elemMatch" : { "63173253349670" : { "$regex" : ".*?出库.*" } } }] } }] }] } }
```

Comment: In that println output there are 2 extra `$or` wrapping the $match query, where did these come from

Answer (score 0):

You might try simplifying that query a bit:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: 
     {$and: [
        {"tissue_backups.23c5bd57da4e461caae0bbf2b06997b8.63173253349670": 
            {$regex: ".*?正常.*"}
        },
        {"tissue_backups.23c5bd57da4e461caae0bbf2b06997b8.63173253349670": 
            {$regex: ".*?出库.*"}
        }
     ]}
  }
])
```

(see that query in [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NrFj9iydOyC))

Then in Java:

```
BasicDBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match",
  new BasicDBObject("$and", Arrays.asList( 
    new BasicDBObject("tissue_backups.23c5bd57da4e461caae0bbf2b06997b8.63173253349670",
      new BasicDBObject("$regex",".*?正常.*")
    ),
    new BasicDBObject("tissue_backups.23c5bd57da4e461caae0bbf2b06997b8.63173253349670",
      new BasicDBObject("$regex",".*?出库.*")
    ),
  ))
)
```

Comment: that will change the query logic,'tissue_backups.23c5bd57da4e461caae0bbf2b06997b8' is an array,and I want to query the array that contains two values(at least one '正常' and at least one '出库'),the query above will result nothing,because one element can not be ‘正常’ and '出库' at the same time.

Comment: This query does exactly what you want.  If `"tissue_backups.23c5bd57da4e461caae0bbf2b06997b8"` is an array of objects, querying for `"tissue_backups.23c5bd57da4e461caae0bbf2b06997b8.63173253349670"` will match if any object in the array has a matching field `63173253349670`. Follow the link to the playground to see it in action.

Comment: thank you,you're right.I tried in mongo client and it works,but the java code still throws the same exception.